# How to write a shellscript that will programmatically kill a process?

Tags: solaris

I have been using the following way to kill a process manually

```
ps -ef | grep process
kill -9 process id of process
start the process again
```

But i think how to do it programmitically as in write in a shellscript
i just have to run e.g. ./restartProcess.sh

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

use an editor to create a file named restartProcess.sh

```
kill $(pgrep process)
start the process again
```

Put the above in it, then chmod +x restartProcess.sh

several points -

Just use kill pid,  this allows the process to cleanup if it was written reasonably well.

```
kill $(pgrep process)
```

is the solaris version of the first two lines of your script.